# ggplot2 interaction use only first character

Tags: r, ggplot2, interaction

in a project i present barplots and use the interaction command to order the groups, as one is a strict subgroup of the other. I would like to not print out the whole name of the first group as this takes up a lot of space. Is there a way to restrict the word to the first character or something like that?

```
mtcars$name <- rownames(mtcars) 
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=interaction(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$name)))+
geom_bar()+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1,vjust = 0.5))
```

Here for example only the #cylinders are interesting to me, I just use the car name to order them. But they take up a lot of space. Just having the first letter of the car written would be ideal. so i would like to have 8.A for example. In my original data the first variable has different length (not just 1 character as #cylinder has here)

Thanks for any answer,
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the labels using regular expressions in `scale_x_discrete` :

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=interaction(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$name)))+
  geom_bar()+
  xlab('Interaction cyl vs Name') + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1,vjust = 0.5)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) sub('(\\..).*', '\\1', x))
```

[image]

Everything inside `()` is referred to as a capture group where we specify which part of the text we want to keep. Here, we mention that we want to keep everything until a dot (i.e `\\.`, `.` is a special character in regex which needs to be escaped with `\\`) followed by another character (`.`).

Comment: In my normal project i have a complex length for the first variable. unlike #cyl is always length 1 i have different length for all. is there any way i can detect the length of the first variable name and give it to substring?

Comment: Thanks alot! this update works fine now. However i would love to keep the first letter after the "." if possible

Comment: @Duesser I edited my answer again to keep 1st letter after ".". Can you check now?

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what i wanted! can you explain how this function works, so i will be able to modify it in the future myself? function(x) sub('(\\..).*', '\\1', x))

more specifically:how can i change it to display 2 characters after "." as an example

Comment: I added some explanation of the regex in the answer. To display 2 characters you can do `scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) sub('(\\..{2}).*', '\\1', x))`